# How can I downgrade to a specific gcc version on Fedora 39?

Tags: fedora, dnf

I need to downgrade from `gcc-13` to `gcc-12` for multiple projects to compile. I couldn't find a straight forward way of doing so.

`dnf list gcc` just shows me version 13.

Comment: See: [Debian Bullseye: Install gcc-11.4.0 and dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767474/debian-bullseye-install-gcc-11-4-0-and-dependencies).  Different OS, but same issue.  Fedora 39 was most likely built with GCC 13 and it's dependencies

Comment: Took me a minute to find this question again but I wrote a question and answer for situations like yours, using this question as the example.  See: [I'm Using Distribution $X That was shipped With Compiler $Y, but I Need Compiler Version $Z](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767757/im-using-distribution-x-that-was-shipped-with-compiler-y-but-i-need-compiler)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I force dnf to install an old version of a package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266888/can-i-force-dnf-to-install-an-old-version-of-a-package)

Comment: @cinemassacres that only works if the older package is available in the repositories; the Fedora 39 repositories only provide GCC 13.

Answer (score -1):

You can install using a specific name-version as described in the man page:

```
dnf install gcc-12.0.0-0.3.fc36
```

To view all versions of a package in your enabled repositories, use:

```
dnf --showduplicates list <package>
```